# Mathematical expression for Loopback 3 between query on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using `loopback 3` and `MongoDB`.

Loopback 3 has between operator and I use it as follows.

```
whereQuery.progress = { between: [25, 50] };
```

Which is the correct mathematical expression for above and why?

1. 25 < progress < 50
2. 25 ≤ progress < 50
3. 25 ≤ progress ≤ 50
4. 25 ≤ progress ≤ 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [25 ≤ progress ≤ 50](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#operators).

Quoting from the linked docs:

> True if the value is between the two specified values: greater than or equal to first value and less than or equal to second value.